# How can I convert a categorical index to a float?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a categorical index of wind directions in a pandas dataframe.

```
print (self.Groups.index)

CategoricalIndex([22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5],
categories=[22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5],
ordered=True, name='Dir', dtype='category')
```

I am trying to use this index to plot a wind rose eg.

```
 ax.bar(self.Groups.index,self.Groups['wind_speed'])
```

but I need to convert the index to radians for it to properly display on a polar plot.

Is there a way to convert the the Categorical index to a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `to_numeric` function to convert the index. It gives more control of the expected behavior in case of failure.

```
# Test data
index = pd.CategoricalIndex([22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5],
categories=[22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5],
ordered=True, name='Dir', dtype='category')
index
df = DataFrame([22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5], index=index)

# Converting the index
df.index = pd.to_numeric(df.index)
print(df.index)

# Float64Index([22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5], dtype='float64', name='Dir')
```

Comment: I had tried this initially and it didn't seem to work, but turns out I was running pandas 0.16.2  I needed to update to 0.19.0 and it works fine now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use `astype` to perform the conversion:

```
self.Groups.index = self.Groups.index.astype('float')
```